# Thinking of sohcahtoa with 90 in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I know the answers from a unit circle. But when looking at a triangle how do you interpret

```
  Angle C
   sin C =
   cos C = 
   tan C =
```

I know the cos 90 = 0 and tan 90 is undefined. But how do you explain that with only this triangle and trying to apply the rules of sohcahtoa? What's the adjacent side for cos C? How does 0 end up being the adjacent side for cos C? How is tan C undefined just looking at the triangle below?

[image: right triangle]

Answer (score 1):

In your triangle, imagine taking angle $B$ and slowly increasing it until it is almost equal to $90^\circ$; for example, let:
$$
\angle B = 89.9999999^\circ
$$
Then you'll notice that the line segments $AB$ and $AC$ will be almost parallel. Intuitively, they are nearly equivalent and approaching infinity; for example, let:
$$
AB = 9999999 \text{ and } AC = 9999998
$$
Compared to these two sides, the third side will be really small and approaching zero; for example, let:
$$
BC = 0.0000001
$$
Thus, in a hand-wavy intuitive sense, we can say that:
\begin{align*}
\sin 90^\circ &\approx \sin B = \frac{9999998}{9999999} \approx 1 \\
\cos 90^\circ &\approx \cos B = \frac{0.0000001}{9999999} \approx 0 \\
\tan 90^\circ &\approx \tan B = \frac{9999998}{0.0000001} \approx \infty ~~~~~~\text{(undefined)} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: I agree thank you very much. I'll use that explanation!

Comment: The only issue is I plan on having students applying the sohcahtoa rules for all three angles A B and C. So the issue arises when they get to finding the sin, cos, and tan for C students intuitively aren't going to think about this.

Comment: All they're going to think and know for the most part is that I have find the cos C just like I found the cos A and cos B. I find the adjacent side and the hypotenuse and write the equation. I need an explanation for students to do that or just take the evaluating ratios for 90 degrees out and do an explanation like the one you wrote above if needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Law of sines:**

$$\frac{\sin{A}}{BC}=\frac{\sin{B}}{AC}=\frac{\sin{C}}{AB} $$

$$\Rightarrow \sin{C}=\frac{AB}{AC} \sin{B}=\frac{5}{4} \sin{B}$$

$$\sin{B}=\frac{ \text{ opposite }}{\text{ hypotenuse }}=\frac{4}{5}$$

So, $$\sin{C}=\frac{5}{4} \frac{4}{5}=1$$

$$$$

**Law of cosines:**

$$\cos{C}=\frac{(AC)^2+(BC)^2-(AB)^2}{2(AC)(BC)}=\frac{16+9-25}{24}=0$$

$$$$

Comment: Yes! Thanks that's what I was looking for!!!

Comment: Of course the sine and cosine of a right angle can’t be defined using *sohcahtoa*, but one you believe the laws of sines and cosines, this is the best way.